# Display upside down text in an Html5 canvas

Tags: html, canvas

How do you display an upside-down text in an html5 canvas? It would help a lot if you could provide a sample working code. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `rotate` transformation. You can read more about it here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Transformations

Code example:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d'); 
ctx.translate(100,100);  
ctx.save();
ctx.rotate(Math.PI);  
ctx.fillText("TEST", 10, 10);
ctx.restore();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uyLNr/

Comment: or `ctx.scale(1, -1);` instead of `ctx.rotate` if you want a horizontal mirror

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/166266/Making-Text-Upside-down-using-CSS